Products of algebraic groups and sums of Lie algebras
Let $G$ be a connected solvable algebraic group. Then we know $G = T \ltimes G_u$ is a semi-direct product, where $T$ is a maximal tori, $G_u$ is the unipotent part of $G$.
Main Question. Why does this imply the following equality of Lie algebras?
$$
L(G) = L(T) \oplus L(G_u)
$$
This appears, for example in Borel's Linear Algebraic Groups, Proof of Proposition 13.14. Maybe I'm missing some algebraic geometry observations?
Thoughts and Discussion.
To what extent is the same statement true when $H_1, H_1 \leq G$ are closed subgroups such that $m\colon H_1 \times H_2 \to G, m(h_1,h_2) = h_1 h_2$ is bijective?
Does $m$ being surjective or dominant alone imply already $L(H_1) + L(H_2) = L(G)$? Is separability relevant here?
If I only know $m$ injective, i.e. $H_1 \cap H_2 = \{e\}$, does this imply $L(H_1) \oplus L(H_2) \hookrightarrow L(G)$?

I don't think that it is a direct sum of Lie algebras. It is $L(G)=L(T)\ltimes T(G_u)$.

@DietrichBurde Thanks for your comment, but what do you mean by a semi direct product of Lie algebras?

See for example nlab, or any book on Lie algebras for the semidirect product of Lie algebras, e.g., in the Levi decomposition.
